# Cpan Install - No Bareword Allowed (windows)

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

I've inherited a project in Perl - an environment I know very little about. Nobody else knows anything about it either and nobody knows how to even get it running natively. So the project is developed by using a cloned VM of the AWS instance, and I'm getting fed up at keeping things in sync between the VM and my local machine. So I'm trying to get the project to run on Windows.

I have installed Strawberry Perl.

There is a cpanfile that contains:

```
Docker/cpanfile;
requires 'Time::Piece';
requires 'File::Slurp';
```

And `Docker/cpanfile` contains:

```
requires 'Time::Format';
requires 'Carton';
requires 'curry';
requires 'IO::Socket::SSL', '2.009';
requires 'Mojolicious', '8.40';
requires 'JSON::MaybeXS';
requires 'Mojo::mysql';
requires 'DateTime';
requires 'Mojo::JSON';
requires 'Data::Dumper';
requires 'Data::Dumper::Compact';
requires 'Data::Dump';
requires 'Mojo::UserAgent';
requires 'Storable';
requires 'DateTime::Format::ISO8601';
requires 'DateTime::Format::ISO8601::Format';
requires 'DateTime::Format::MySQL';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI';
requires 'Mojo::JWT';
requires 'File::Slurper';
requires 'Text::Table';
requires 'DateTime::Span';
requires 'Data::Format::Pretty::Console';
requires 'WebService::GoogleAPI::Client';
requires 'Email::Sender::Simple';
requires 'Email::Stuffer';
requires 'MIME::Base64::URLSafe';
requires 'Crypt::PBKDF2';
requires 'Try::Tiny';
requires 'Date::Calc::Iterator';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::PODViewer';
requires 'Term::ProgressBar';
requires 'List::Util';
requires 'Data::Printer';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2';
requires 'Excel::Writer::XLSX';
requires 'Text::Table::Any';
requires 'PDF::API2';
requires 'GD';
requires 'Text::Table::HTML';
requires 'String::Interpolate';
requires 'MIME::Base64';
requires 'Algorithm::Permute';
requires 'Time::HiRes';
requires 'Benchmark::Object';
requires 'Devel::Size';
requires 'Set::Scalar';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::WriteExcel';
requires 'Array::Utils';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::RenderFile';
requires 'Test::mysqld';
requires 'Getopt::Long';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::Minion';
requires 'Minion::Backend::mysql';
requires 'Mojolicious::Plugin::Minion::Admin';
requires 'HTTP::UA::Parser';
requires 'TAP::Formatter::HTML';
requires 'App::Yath';
```

Looks fairly basic to me.
Yet running `cpanm --installdeps` in git bash yields:

```
Configuring /c/sites/ProjectName... FAIL
! Parsing cpanfile failed: Bareword "Docker" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at cpanfile line 1.
Bareword "cpanfile" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at cpanfile line 1.
! Configuring . failed. See /c/Users/joshd/.cpanm/work/1657148855.2012/build.log for details.
```

So do I have to disable strictness of some sort? Or is there something I should be changing.
Also despite the "Docker" reference, there is not a Docker Image and the docker file is I think years out of date so I don't think that's a way to go.

Comment: `strict` comes from the cpanfile module, so you can't disable it, and it is 100% the wrong solution. The error comes from the line `Docker/cpanfile;`. Are you sure that is correct syntax?

Comment: No I'm not, but it is what is in the repo. I assumed it was correct syntax for referencing the other cpanfile.

Just running installdeps on the Docker/cpanfile gives me the issue:

`Can't locate ExtUtils/Manifest.pm in @INC (you may need to install the ExtUtils::Manifest module) (@INC contains: FatPacked::34360227712=HASH(0x800077780) /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at /c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpanm line 119.`
Which is progress, I guess

Comment: Okay that second issue was a result of using Git Bash. Using powershell it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Docker/cpanfile;` divides `Docker` by `cpanfile` and discards the result. That's not very useful. That's not very correct. Silencing the error message is not the correct approach.

I think you want

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
do( "$RealBin/Docker/cpanfile" )
   or die( $@ // $! );
```

Comment: I think that line was meant to be commented out, just to let people know that the cpanfile had moved. 

I think. Not really sure. Anyways, there were packages completely incompatible with Windows and the whole app apparently has to be run as a service. So I've got a long road ahead.

Comment: Comments start with `#`. /// Consider WSL2. It's a VM for Linux built right into Windows. You can install you fav distro. (Or even more than one.) For example, I run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

*cpanfile* is roughly Perl code (which I think is a bad idea, but people were really into what they thought were DSLs). There is some sanity checking, but at some point someone is going to figure out something clever to use it as an attack vector to run arbitrary code.

Not that I have an alternative, but it is something that I've been thinking a lot about lately.